# I deleted a Promotion on Google CSE. Why doesn't it disappear?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

I deleted a Promotion on Google CSE. Why doesn't it disappear?

I took no other other other than to delete the promotion, yet is still appears using the promoted keyword. This occurs not only on my site, but also on the CSE test search instance to the right.

I even when so far as to download the Promotions XML file and search it. There is no trace of the Promotion, as expected.

Could find no answers on Google. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: google suggest CSE questions be asked on stack overflow with custom search tag - eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-custom-search

Comment: Thanks, I asked the same over there. Should I delete this one?